# Related Rates- Snowball Melting...

Tags: calculus, geometry, area, volume, spheres

Assume that a snowball melts in such a way that its volume decreases at a rate proportional to its surface area. If half the original snowball has melted away after 2 hours, how much longer will it take for the snowball to disappear completely? (Answer = (2/(cuberoot(2) - 1)) or 7.69 hours)

Comment: I have the same one to your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let r be radius, then (dr/dt) = ((r^3)/2) * (1 - (1/ cube root(2)). Volume of sphere is proportional to radius. Therefore, the volume will diminish to zero after x hours: r^3 - (r^3/2)*{(1 - 1/(cube root 2))}*x = 0. X - 2 equals what you have.

Let r be radius, then ${dr \over dt}$ = $ r^3 \over 2$ * (1 - $1 \over (\sqrt[3]{2})$). Volume of sphere is proportional to radius. Therefore, the volume will diminish to zero after x hours: $ r^3$ - $ r^3 \over 2$ * (1 - $1 \over (\sqrt[3]{2})$)*x.  x - 2 equals what you have.